# C# AutoMapper, How to map group count

Tags: c#, automapper

My model:

```
public class StatusDetailsViewModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public long CountNo { get; set; }
}
```

And my function to get the data:

```
public List<StatusDetailsViewModel> CheckMeetingStatus(long actionId)
{
     List<StatusDetailsViewModel> statusDetails;

     var statuses = _igniteDb.myTable.Where(a => a.actionId == actionId)
                .GroupBy(a => new { a.Status, a.ElectionGroup }).GroupBy(c => new { c.Key.Status})
                .Select(b => new { Status = b.Key.Status, CountNo = b.Count()}).ToList();

     //How to Map statuses to statusDetails??

     return statusDetails;
}
```

I've being trying to use auto mapper to achieve this. But I am not sure how to configure my mapper. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have to map at in your code. Instead of creating anonymous type, you can create the object of  `StatusDetailsViewModel`. Change the select statement as `.Select(b => new StatusDetailsViewModel() { Status = b.Key.Status, CountNo = b.Count()}`

Comment: If you want to use AutoMapper then you should define the source and target types while defining the Map/profile. You can not map the anonymous type with AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to map at in your code. Instead of creating anonymous type, you can create the object of `StatusDetailsViewModel`. Change the select statement as `Select(b => new StatusDetailsViewModel() { Status = b.Key.Status, CountNo = b.Count()}`

If you want to use **AutoMapper** then you should define the source and target types while defining the Map/profile. You can not map the anonymous type with AutoMapper.

Your code to create the object of `StatusDetailsViewModel` (without using Automapper as you don't require for the code you have asked for)

```
public List<StatusDetailsViewModel> CheckMeetingStatus(long actionId)
{
     List<StatusDetailsViewModel> statusDetails;

     var statuses = _igniteDb.myTable.Where(a => a.actionId == actionId)
                .GroupBy(a => new { a.Status, a.ElectionGroup }).GroupBy(c => new { c.Key.Status})
                .Select(b => new StatusDetailsViewModel () { Status = b.Key.Status, CountNo = b.Count()}).ToList();

     //How to Map statuses to statusDetails??

     return statusDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you're returning a `List<StatusDetailsViewModel>`, you don't need AutoMapper here just project your data by using directly your view model like below:

```
List<StatusDetailsViewModel> statusDetails = _igniteDb.myTable.Where(a => a.actionId == actionId)
     .GroupBy(a => new { a.Status, a.ElectionGroup })
     .GroupBy(c => new { c.Key.Status})
     .Select(b => new StatusDetailsViewModel { /* <--- Here you instantiate your view model */
          Status = b.Key.Status, 
          CountNo = b.Count()}
     ).ToList();
```